# Best way to access averaged static data in a Database (Hibernate, Postgres)

Tags: database, postgresql, hibernate, average

Currently I have a project (written in Java) that reads sensor output from a micro controller and writes it across several Postgres tables every second using Hibernate. In total I write about 130 columns worth of data every second. Once the data is written it will stay static forever.This system seems to perform fine under the current conditions.

My question is regarding the best way to query and average this data in the future. There are several approaches I think would be viable but am looking for input as to which one would scale and perform best.

Being that we gather and write data every second we end up generating more than 2.5 million rows per month. We currently plot this data via a JDBC select statement writing to a JChart2D (i.e. SELECT pressure, temperature, speed FROM data WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN startTime AND endTime). The user must be careful to not specify too long of a time period (startTimem and endTime delta < 1 day) or else they will have to wait several minutes (or longer) for the query to run.

The future goal would be to have a user interface similar to the Google visualization API that powers Google Finance. With regards to time scaling, i.e. the longer the time period the "smoother" (or more averaged) the data becomes.

Options I have considered are as follows:

**Option A:** Use the SQL avg function to return the averaged data points to the user. I think this option would get expensive if the user asks to see the data for say half a year. I imagine the interface in this scenario would scale the amount of rows to average based on the user request. I.E. if the user asks for a month of data the interface will request an avg of every 86400 rows which would return ~30 data points whereas if the user asks for a day of data the interface will request an avg of every 2880 rows which will also return 30 data points but of more granularity.

**Option B:** Use SQL to return all of the rows in a time interval and use the Java interface to average out the data. I have briefly tested this for kicks and I know it is expensive because I'm returning 86400 rows/day of interval time requested. I don't think this is a viable option unless there's something I'm not considering when performing the SQL select.

**Option C:** Since all this data is static once it is written, I have considered using the Java program (with Hibernate) to also write tables of averages along with the data it is currently writing. In this option, I have several java classes that "accumulate" data then average it and write it to a table at a specified interval (5 seconds, 30 seconds, 1 minute, 1 hour, 6 hours and so on). The future user interface plotting program would take the interval of time specified by the user and determine which table of averages to query. This option seems like it would create a lot of redundancy and take a lot more storage space but (in my mind) would yield the best performance?

**Option D:** Suggestions from the more experienced community?

Comment: I'm not asking for code, I'm asking for advice or opinions...

Comment: This is clearly not a question of writing code.  It's a question of what tools to use and where to put the code organizationally. +1 just because...

Comment: Thanks, not looking for code at all or even an in depth description, just looking for opinions from people who have more experience with this than I do. I mean something like this must have been done before correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option A won't tend to scale very well once you have large quantities of data to pass over; Option B will probably tend to start relatively slow compared to A and scale even more poorly.  Option C is a technique generally referred to as "materialized views", and you might want to implement this one way or another for best performance and scalability.  While PostgreSQL doesn't yet support *declarative* materialized views (but I'm working on that this year, personally), there are ways to get there through triggers and/or scheduled jobs.

To keep the inserts fast, you probably *don't* want to try to maintain any views off of triggers on the primary table.  What you might want to do is to periodically summarize detail into summary tables from crontab jobs (or similar).  You might also want to create views to show summary data by using the summary tables which have been created, combined with detail table where the summary table doesn't exist.

The materialized view approach would probably work better for you if you *partition* your raw data by date range.  That's probably a really good idea anyway.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Now I have an idea of what to research.